# Program not giving any output, when I use Continue

Tags: c++

I am a beginner to C++ Programming. I tried to make a simple program to learn the `continue` statement. But, when I use `continue` statement for skipping an iteration of the loop, the program runs but doesn't show any output. Any Help?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    for (int j=1; j < 13; j++)
    {if(j=8) continue; 
        for (int i=1; i<j+1; i++)
        {cout << setw(4) << i*j;}
        cout << endl;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Try `j==8` instead of `j=8`.

Comment: `j=8` is an assignment and it's value (converted to `bool`) always `true`. Hence, the rest of loop body is skipped always but your loop will run forever.

Comment: To illustrate this, you may insert a `cout << j;` before the `if` and you will get `19999999999999999999999999999` and so on.

Comment: OT: Better than `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`: `#include <iostream>` and `#include <iomanip>`.

Comment: try putting integer literal on the left side `if(8=j)`

Answer (score 3):

We use `==` instead of `=` for comparision.
The `=` is an assignment operator we generally use it to initialize values.

```
 int main() {

        for (int j=1; j < 13; j++){
        if(j==8) continue; 
            for (int i=1; i<j+1; i++){
            cout << setw(4) << i*j;
               }
            cout << endl;
        }   
    }
```